# How proceed when OP overrides my edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

This is my first post here and I'm sorry if this has been asked before. Please see this question: [How to call Stored Procedure and prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531206/how-to-call-stored-procedure-and-prepared-statement#comment27267161_18531206)

The thing is a couple of days I helped a new user to solve his/her problem, guiding him/her to right way through comments. In one of these comments I asked the OP to add exception stack trace and he/she did it in a comment. So I edited the question adding this stack trace and the edit was accepted by other people. Then I deleted most of my comments because these became unnecessary. But the OP edited his/her question again deleting my edits. Consequently the question remains incomplete and the entire post (including answers) does not make much sense. Anyway I just added (couple of minutes ago) the stack trace to an early answer I posted attempting to make the post a little more understandable to people who is looking for a similar problem.

I would like to know how to proceed when this situations happen. Should I flag the question? Should I re-edit the question? Or should I leave the question just as OP wants? I guess the OP has his/her a reasons to delete my edits so what should I do?

Comment: It's not a particularly good question in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean my question or OP's question? If mine please let me know how to improve it.

Comment: Sorry - the question that you were referring to, not your own.  There's no explanation of what specifically needs to be done, what seems to be the problem and there doesn't seem to be much effort placed into the post.  With so many posts on Stack Overflow, those types of questions _should_ eventually fall by the wayside.

Comment: Yes I think you're totally right. But anyway I wanted to help the OP to improve and I've had some doubts about how handle this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are well over 5 million questions on the site.  We all try to make every question as good as possible, but sometimes the OP doesn't cooperate.  In that case, I'd respect the OP's decision to delete my edits.  After all, it's only 0.00002% of all the questions on the site.

The last thing you want is to get into some kind of edit war (even if you're right).

Comment: Thanks, it's a very good point! Of course I didn't even thought in an edit-war. Anyhow it's an OP decision and I have to respect that. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: @dic19 Once OP has a useable answer, why do you have to respect it? OP is not special, just an editor like any other and should try to make the question and answer as good as possible for those that find it later.

Comment: @EbiDK yes, it's a valid and good point too. But I think OP has his/her reasons and well, since he/she is the one that owned the question I think he/she is in his/her right to reject my edits and I shouldn't start an argument because of this. Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

There is not much point in trying to read much into why the OP chose to delete/revert your edits.  However, by doing so the OP is certainly not helping improve the question.

Of course, the chosen action would vary from individual to individual.  I wouldn't either choose to edit the question further given that the changes are being reverted, nor flag the question.  In such cases, I'd prefer to move away from the question.  Low quality questions tend to be ignored anyways.